# How to get products by ProductCategoryID?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

its my **unlimited categories** table:

[image]

is my **products** table

[image]

**my problem is:** how to get product by ProductCategoryID?
[image]

**stored procedures:**
[image]

**asp.net**

[image]

Comment: Add `sp_getMultipleProducts` as well

Comment: Your not passing category_id to SP?

Comment: sp_getMultipleProduct takes in ProductId.

Seems to be a contradiction going on there.

Perhaps it should take in ProductCategoryId?

Comment: Variable *mycommand* is not used and can be removed.

Comment: Your stored procedure does not filter on product category, so it will return all products.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the WHERE clause and add *@ProductCategoryID int* as parameter, just as you did with language.

```
... AND Products.ProductCategoryID = @ProductCategoryID
```

Comment: Ah, I see you just updated your stored procedure and extended the WHERE clause.

Comment: i add Products.ProductCategoryID = @ProductCategoryID but now i cant get any products?

Comment: Something went wrong with the declaration of the *@Lang* parameter, so I'm surprised you could execute the ALTER statement.

Comment: Also note that you're not returning the category name anymore, only all the fields of the product table.

Comment: i want to get Product Name and Picture

Comment: Pls help me where iş the problem?

Comment: But why have you removed the `Products.ProductCategoryID = @ProductCategoryID` again then? And if you only need the product name and picture, why include other fields? And why the INNER JOIN with the *Categories* table if you don't need any field from that table? And what is the extra closing bracket at the first line of the stored procedure doing there?